# AppleScript search for safari tab

Tags: applescript, safari

I used this script for years but since the last macOS update I can't understand why, this doesn't seems to work anymore (PS I changed the URL/TAB name for a demo)

```
set searchpat to "Google"
tell application "Safari"
    set winlist to every window
    set winmatchlist to {}
    set tabmatchlist to {}
    set tabnamematchlist to {}
    repeat with win in winlist
        set ok to true
        try
            set tablist to every tab of win
        on error errmsg
            --display dialog name of win as string
            set ok to false
        end try
        if ok then
            repeat with t in tablist
                if searchpat is in (name of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & 2 & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    set myid to (id of win as string)
                    ##return (index of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                else if searchpat is in (URL of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & 2 & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    set w to item 1 of winmatchlist
    set t to item 1 of tabmatchlist
    
    set current tab of w to t
    set index of w to 1
end tell


set changedfordemo to "https://www.google.com"
tell application "Safari"
    tell window id myid
        set URL of tab 1 to changedfordemo
    end tell
end tell
```

it's just open the URL at tab 1 in the last safari window open instead of searching for the correct window and changing the URL for this window in tab 1

Comment: Give us a clue then, which line errors?

Comment: there is no error but it's doesn't seems to look for the window id anymore "myid" and just open the tab in whatever last window was open (I use two safari windows, and I use this script to find what window have this website open and change the URL)

Comment: RE: "but since the last macOS update" -- This is ambitious, please state the exact version of **macOS** are you running.

Comment: I'm running 11.4 (20F71)

Comment: Okay, in a clean install of **macOS Big Sur** 11.4, I copied and pasted the **AppleScript** _code_ shown in your OP into **Script Editor** and ran it with two _windows_ in **Safari**, one having multiple _tabs_ with one of the _tabs_ having **Google** in it but not the _current tab_ of the _window_, and a second _window_ being _frontmost_ without **Google** in it.  The _tab_ having **Google** in it became the _current tab_ and the _window_ containing it was brought forward. So if that not what it's supposed to do, then you need to clarify the issue.

Comment: thanks, I suppose this I something with my system them, perhaps a change through mobile management / JAMF from my company.